# Why the Camera is not changing the position like the player does?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Teleport : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject player;
    public Camera mainCamera;
    public Camera firstCam;
    public Camera camera;
    private List<GameObject> TeleportBooths;

    private void Start()
    {
        InstantiateObjects gos = GetComponent<InstantiateObjects>();

        TeleportBooths = new List<GameObject>();
        TeleportBooths = gos.PrefabsList();
        firstCam.enabled = false;
        mainCamera.enabled = false;
        camera.enabled = true;
        player.transform.position = TeleportBooths[0].transform.position;
        camera.transform.position = TeleportBooths[0].transform.position;
        for (int i = 0; i < TeleportBooths.Count; i++)
        {
            TeleportBooths[i].AddComponent<TeleportationsCore>();
        }
    }
}
```

I have 3 cameras in the hierarchy.
Each one position in other place.
The newest camera i added now is camera.
And in the script i want it to be position in the same place where the player is.
So first i tried with only one Camera variable in the script. And then did in the Start:

```
Camera.main.enabled = false;
camera.Enabled = true;
camera.transform.position = TeleportBooths[0].transform.position;
```

But it keep showing the Main Camera view when running the game and not the view of camera. In the Scene view i can see that camera is position now where the player is but it keep showing the Main Camera view.

So i added variables for the main camera and the firstCamera and set them both to enabled false and yet it's showing the main camera not camera.

Comment: `camera.Enabled = true;`

this should probably be `camera.enabled = true;` not sure that solves your issue though. Make sure all your cameras are also tagged with MainCamera

Comment: If you have more than one camera active in a scene, they will render in order of depth, from lowest to highest. If they all have clear flags (skybox, or solid color) then each one will overwrite what the last one did (don't clear and depth only will have an overlay effect, if the camera would ordinarily render the skybox, it instead renders nothing, letting the previous camera's result show through).